# Completion Handler called in IBAction Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I am debugging an old project which has got a old library. I am not sure how they have called the block handler from button action method. They have a Class where they have declared a method

```
+ (void) method: (NSString *) parameter;
```

In which I guess, they are adding cancel button and action method for the button. They have declared a block as

```
typedef void (^simpleBlock)(void);

@property (nonatomic, copy) simpleBlock simpleBlock;
```

And when it is implemented in ViewController class it is called as

```
[ClassName method:@"parameter"].simpleBlock = ^{
        //Do something
    };
```

How they would have linked the block with button action and the method because I couldn't see as it is library, got just header file. Any help on understanding this implementation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For invoking a block on any action we code like this ,

In a `TotalLikes_Comments.h` ,

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^LikeButtonTapAction)(TotalLikes_Comments *aCell);

- (IBAction)openLikesClick:(id)sender;
```

In `TotalLikes_Comments.m` Actual Implementation of method is

```
- (IBAction)openLikesClick:(id)sender {
    if (self.openLikesTapAction) {
        self.openLikesTapAction(self);
    }
}
```

Where whenever the button clicks this block is initializes with the object of class ,

Whenever we want the action no need to write theaction code in the class file just write your code where you have initialized the class eg.in cellforrow atIndexpath

```
cell.LikeButtonTapAction = ^(TotalLikes_Comments *aCell){
  // Do your stuff.
};
```

Above is the logic for Invoking Block in IBAction.
But In your scenario this is written in Frameworks. In which the the Ibaction Logic is hidden from all. eg.

```
if(self.openLikesTapAction) {
     self.openLikesTapAction(self);
  }
```

Hope you got an idea from this.